# Do java .class files have a lexer/parser?

Tags: java, compiler, jit

I've been learning ANTLR, by writing my own (extremely simple!) programming language

It made me curious about how the lexer/parser/AST is implemented for java. Obviously there is a grammar for `.java` files and this gets parsed down to ByteCode, which is then validated to check that all is syntactically and sementically correct and then finally a `.class` file is written out, but I wondered what happens when you run

`java -cp '.' Foo`

I assume `Foo.class` has to be read in - but does this (the bytecode in the `.class` file) then have a grammar of it's own? or is the AST that is formed when the `.java` file was compiled just written to disk in binary form, and then just slurped into memory when the `java.exe` program runs

I was thinking that it probably does have an AST, as this is probably the essence of what a JIT compiler really is.

Comment: Generally speaking, the purpose of compiling to bytecode is that a bytecode format of simple opcode-argument tuples can be easily executed by computers without all that expensive lexing/parsing/AST nonsense that our human-readable languages require. But I'm not familiar enough with the JVM to give concrete examples, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Yes.  You are looking for chapter 4 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification: [The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically speaking, there is a parser, but practically speaking, the parser is so trivial, that you typically don't call it a "parser". After all, the JVM bytecode format is *specifically* designed for being fast and easy to read by a *machine* and not at all to be readable by humans.

It's basically some fixed-size fields of fixed types and some variable-length arrays of fixed types whose length is provided in a fixed-size field of a fixed type at a fixed location.